Flutter remove white circle in image splash screen
I've problem in flutter splash screen this image
the image dont have backgroundcolor is png .
in flutter splash screen
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Modify this file to customize your launch splash screen -->
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/black" />

    <!-- You can insert your own image assets here -->
     <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="fill"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" 
            android:width="100dp"
            android:height="100dp"
            />
    </item> 
</layer-list>

android->src-> main-> values -> color.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <color name="black">#000000</color>
</resources>

android->src-> main-> values -> style.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- Theme applied to the Android Window while the process is starting when the OS's Dark Mode setting is off -->
    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        <!-- Show a splash screen on the activity. Automatically removed when
             the Flutter engine draws its first frame -->
        
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
    </style>
    <!-- Theme applied to the Android Window as soon as the process has started.
         This theme determines the color of the Android Window while your
         Flutter UI initializes, as well as behind your Flutter UI while its
         running.

         This Theme is only used starting with V2 of Flutter's Android embedding. -->
    <style name="NormalTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">?android:colorBackground</item>
    </style>
</resources>



You can also try to create splash screen using flutter_native_splash package. This package has a good documentation on pub.dev
